# Runtime Dependencies on ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1 for RISC-V (rv64ima)

Tags: zip, yocto, ld, bitbake, riscv

I am trying to build an image using Yocto for **rv64ima** isa with abi as **lp64** . But many packages such as **zip, unzip** have runtime dependencies on **ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1** .I am attaching the error snippet below.
Is is possible to compile these packages for an architecture (RISC-V) not have double or floating point units?
Thank You.

EDIT 1: How do I solve this below mentioned error in Yocto? This is happening with several packages not only **zip**.

```
ERROR: zip-3.0-r2 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/zipsplit contained in package zip requires ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_zip? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: zip-3.0-r2 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/zipsplit contained in package zip requires ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_zip? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: zip-3.0-r2 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although the rv64ima does not have float instructions, it is able to run programs that need a floats thanks to the soft-float module. However the difference will be seen at the performance level because it takes longer to do the float operations in soft.